# Can't make the simple Scala Spark application with SBT on Spark official site working

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I run the simple Scala Spark application with SBT in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications, but some exceptions happen. I have been searching around, but am not sure still. 
I am wondering what is  wrong?

Among the many lines of exception reporting, which shall I focus on? The topmost one, correct?

Thanks.

SimpleApp.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // val logFile = "./README.md" // Should be some file on your system    
    val logFile = "/home/t/programs/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
    val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with b: $numBs")
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
```

build:

```
$ sbt package
[info] Loading project definition from /tmp/test/spark/selfcontainedApp/project
[info] Loading settings for project selfcontainedapp from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/tmp/test/spark/selfcontainedApp/)
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Mar 19, 2020, 6:48:35 PM
```

Run:

```
$ ~/programs/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp"   --master local   target/scala-2.12/simple-project_2.12-1.0.jar
20/03/19 18:49:14 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ocean resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.122.1 instead (on interface virbr0)
20/03/19 18:49:14 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/03/19 18:49:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Simple Application
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: t
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: t
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/03/19 18:49:16 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(t); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(t); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33721.
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-1b40e98b-55f2-43d0-a435-1966c12d1f15
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
20/03/19 18:49:17 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.122.1:4040
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/tmp/test/spark/selfcontainedApp/target/scala-2.12/simple-project_2.12-1.0.jar at spark://192.168.122.1:33721/jars/simple-project_2.12-1.0.jar with timestamp 1584658158482
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 35077.
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.122.1:35077
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 35077, None)
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.122.1:35077 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 35077, None)
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 35077, None)
20/03/19 18:49:18 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.122.1, 35077, None)
20/03/19 18:49:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1736)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2030)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1260)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    at SimpleApp$.$deserializeLambda$(SimpleApp.scala)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 63 more
20/03/19 18:49:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1736)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2030)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1260)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    at SimpleApp$.$deserializeLambda$(SimpleApp.scala)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 63 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2835)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2835)
    at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:12)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1736)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2030)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1260)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    at SimpleApp$.$deserializeLambda$(SimpleApp.scala)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 63 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems issue is with build.sbt dependencies:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"`

Could you please try something like below:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "2.4.5"`

And rebuild the jar and try running it again.

For details you can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark

Comment: That doesn't work. `[error] /tmp/test/spark/scala/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:2:8: object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
`

Comment: Try adding below config: 
 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5" libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"

Comment: In general, this issue occurs due to incompatible versions.